# How to show directory files in select using razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

With my current below code I can get the files and output them in a select option but if the user submits the form without selecting a image it will give a error
" Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have merch_image in the model Required.
How do I make the below select using razor so it won't bypass the Required?

controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"//uploads/stamp_images");

        ViewBag.Message = dirInfo.GetFiles().ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<select class="form-control col-sm-3" id="merch_image" name="merch_image">
                        <option selected disabled="disabled">Select</option>

                               @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Message)

                    {
                        <option value="@item.Name"> @item.Name</option>
                    }

    </select>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.merch_image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Unsure how your `select` list would be showing the _array_ based on the above. I don't see a loop (although `@item` suggests there's one...). Typically you'd use `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper for this. Also, where's the code that processes the `POST`? Hopefully it checks if the `Model.IsValid` which does the validation check (before running code that throws the exception).

Comment: opps sorry I just edit to show loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, first its find containing image folder and find which one you find
in folder,

```
                    string ImagePath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/stamp_images");

                       string FileName = 'xyz' + ".png";
                        //check image file exist or not
                        var filters = new String[] { "png" };
                        var files = GetFilesFrom(ImagePath, filters, false);

                            foreach (var item in files)
                            {
                                if (item.Contains(FileName))
                                {
                                   //return contains image
                                }
                            }
```